# Symfony2 'Bundle "default" does not exist'

Tags: symfony

I have build a library using some of the Symfony2 components and Doctrine. I now want to use this library inside a Symfony2 console app. I have included my library through Composer as a vendor, however, I'm getting the following error when I execute my library code:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Bundle "default" does not exist or it is not enabled.' in /home/user/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/DependencyInjection/AbstractDoctrineExtension.php:90
```

I'm not sure what the "default" bundle would be, how this is related to Doctrine or how to start to debug this.

Any help much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

This is the Composer.json for my console app:

```
{
    "name": "my/console",
    "type": "application",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@bitbucket.org:my/library.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "my/library": "dev-dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "My\\": ["src/"]
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Composer.json for my library:

```
{
    "name": "my/library",
    "type": "library",
    "keywords": [
        "my", "library"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://www.mine.com/",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "My\\": ["src/"] }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "underscore/underscore.php": "1.3.1",
        "sami/sami": "v1.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your `composer.json` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see what is causing this in the [AbstractDoctrineExtension](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/DependencyInjection/AbstractDoctrineExtension.php#L89-L91). As you can see, this error has something to do with the **mappings** you have defined in your config file.

It is also mentioned [here](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/03/25/symfony2-getting-started/) that this error is triggered by an error in the mappings, just try to comment out what you have in the mappings.

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            mappings:
                #whatever you have here
```

Comment: If this doesn't work please post your config file (just the orm part).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! The problem was the location of my entities which in the context of the library development are in a different location than when used as an actual library (in which case they are located inside the vendor directory).

Comment: Just wanted to add to my above comment, I fixed by making my Doctrine entities location configurable through the parameters.yml so that in different environments they can be located in different directories.